# Integral of the intensity curve over path difference

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, interference

Suppose the intensity amplitude of an elementary beam is $i_1 (k_0)$ where $k_0$ is the wavenumber. Let $k_0 = 2\pi/\lambda_0$ be the wavenumber corresponding a particular "*desired monochromatic source*" and $ y$ represents the optical path difference. Now,
$$
i_1(k_0)=\begin{cases}i_1 & k_0\in \overline k_0 \pm dk_0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \\ \end{cases}
$$
Put $x=k_0-\overline k_0$ and $j(x)=i_1(\overline k_0 +x)$. Then adding different spectral components incoherently, the total intensity in the interference pattern,
$$
I(y) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} i(k_0,y) dk_0
$$
,where $i(k_0,y) = 2i_1(k_0)\{1+\cos(k_0y)\}$. Then,
$$
I=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} j(x)\{1+\cos[(\overline k_0 +x)y]\}
$$
$$
=2[P+C\cos(\overline k_0 y) -S\sin(\overline k_0 y)]
$$
, where
$$
P=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} j(x) dx,
$$
$$
C=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} j(x)\cos(x y) dx,
$$
$$
S=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} j(x)\sin(x y) dx.
$$
Now, $I(y)$ looks like the integrand in the the Fourier integral of $j(x)$ i.e., my question is, can't we say that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} I(y) dy = j(x) ?
$$
That is, aren't $I(y)$ and $j(x)$ each other's Fourier transform?

Comment: It won't be as you are multiplying C and S with other functions of y. Apart from that unless j(x) is even you have to use complex number i in front of the sine part.

Comment: @Marc Barceló , it doesn't matter at all whether I use real or imaginary form of Fourier integral.

Comment: However the fact that you are multiplying C by another function of y implies that y and x are not conjugates.